# How to retrieve SecretsManager secret in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I'm setting up a Fargate service in AWS using CDK

```
const albFargateService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
    this,
    'FargateService',
    {
        vpc: ...,
        taskImageOptions: {
            image: ...,
            containerPort: ...,
            secrets: {
                MY_ENV_VAR: Secret.fromSecretsManager(
                    **ISecret**,
                    'fieldWithinTheSecret'
                ),
            }
        }
    }
)
```

How am I supposed to get hold of the **ISecret** instance given the name of the secret?

I've looked at the `AWS.SecretsManager` from the AWS SDK, but it only returns strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently there is no `Secret.fromSecretName`-method. Assuming that you are using an existing secret, you should use the `Secret.fromSecretArn`-method.

Note that if you use a KMS key, you should use the `Secret.fromSecretAttributes`-method as described at [Get a value from AWS secrets manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/get_secrets_manager_value.html).

```js
import * as ecs from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs";
import * as ecs_patterns from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs-patterns";
import * as secretsmanager from "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager";

const mySecret = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretArn(this, "mySecret", "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<account-id-number>:secret:<secret-name>-<random-6-characters>");

const albFargateService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
    this,
    'FargateService',
    {
        vpc: ...,
        taskImageOptions: {
            image: ...,
            containerPort: ...,
            secrets: {
                MY_ENV_VAR: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(mySecret),
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Note 1: `Secret.fromSecretArn` and `Secret.fromSecretsManager` come from different namespaces (_@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager_ and _@aws-cdk/aws-ecs_ respectively)

Comment: Now, aws-cdk provides [Secret.fromSecretNameV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-secretsmanager/secret.html#aws_secretsmanager_Secret_fromSecretNameV2) to  import the secret by its Name.

Answer (score 13):

The updated one with CDK version 2
You can refer to a secret either with `Secret.fromSecretNameV2()` and retrieve a particular secret value using `Secret.secretValueFromJson('keyname').toString();`
Refer to the code snippet below

```ts
const appSecret = Secret.fromSecretNameV2(this,'app-secret',"secret-name");
const value1 = appSecret.secretValueFromJson('KeyName1').toString();
const value2 = appSecret.secretValueFromJson('KeyName2').toString();
```

> The best thing is, you can use this secret value anywhere like Cognito
> Secrets,  and it will not hardcode the secret value in your cloud
> formation stack. Instead, it will use a token and it will be resolved
> to the value when it is deployed.

Comment: Sadly, this function is completely useless if you need the full ARN. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18555 for details.

Answer (score 3):

in my case I end up in the following code:

```js
import { Secret } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager'
...
const value = Secret.fromSecretAttributes(this, `unique-stack-id-secret`, {
    secretPartialArn: `arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<accountId>:secret:<secret-name>`,
}).secretValue.unsafeUnwrap()
```

the aws-cdk version is **2.69.0**. [Here is the link to the Secret class documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html)

Comment: Is this the same as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63621932/268091 ?

Comment: It's kind of the same, but here I presented the working usage of `fromSecretAttributes` directly in the answer to the ticket, without forcing the StackOverflow user to go to AWS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve same with the docker container inside ECS and CDKv2. My goal was to get many values located under one Secret placeholder only (One JSON secret with multiple values). And I ended up wit something like this

```js
import * as secretsmanager from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager';
...

const awsSM = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretNameV2(this, 'idForCDK','secretNameInAwsSecretManager');
...
const props: ContainerDefinitionOptions = {
   secrets : {
     ENV_VAR: Secret.fromSecretsManager(awsSM, 'filedNameInsideJsonSecret')
   }
}
```

p.s.

you can also try the `fromSecretPartialArn` instead `fromSecretNameV2` and should also work fine (I did tested it without those `random-6-characters` at the end of ARN though).